# Attributes not being added to Marketing Cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, android, mobilepush-android, attribute

I am attempting to add attributes to Marketing Cloud in the onETPushConfigurationSuccess() method in the application class. etRequestStatus.etPushSdkStatusCode = 0 and the application is able to receive push notification successfully but no attributes will update in the MobilePush Demographics. Is this the proper way to add attributes?

```
/** Register to receive push notifications. */
    try {
        ETPush.configureSdk(new ETPushConfig.Builder(this)
                        .setEtAppId(ET_APP_ID)
                        .setAccessToken(ET_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                        .setLogLevel(Log.VERBOSE)
                        .setGcmSenderId(FCM_SENDER_ID)
                        .setAnalyticsEnabled(false)    // ET Analytics, default = false
                        .setWamaEnabled(false)         // Web & Mobile Analytics, default = false
                        .build()
                , new ETPushConfigureSdkListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onETPushConfigurationSuccess(ETPush etPush, ETRequestStatus etRequestStatus) {
                        // Verify Google Play Services availability and notify the user of any exceptions
                        if (etRequestStatus.getGooglePlayServiceStatusCode() != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS && GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(etRequestStatus.getGooglePlayServiceStatusCode())) {
                            GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().showErrorNotification(getApplicationContext(), etRequestStatus.getGooglePlayServiceStatusCode());
                        }

                        try {
                            boolean attributeAdded = etPush.addAttribute("MemberID", "12345678");
                            if (attributeAdded) {
                                Log.i("debug", "attribute added");
                            } else {
                                Log.i("debug", "attribute NOT added");
                            }
                        } catch (ETException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onETPushConfigurationFailed(ETException e) {
                        // If we're here then your application will _NOT_ receive push notifications.
                        Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "onetech", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
        );
  } catch (ETException e) {
        Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, "debug", e.getMessage());
    }
```

[image]

**Update:**
I am getting "attribute added" in the logs:

```
   D/~!ETPush: configureSdk()
   D/~!ETPush: Resuming as a result of callback? 'true'
   D/~!ETPush: activityPausedThread is not running.  So continue with resuming activity.
   D/~!ETPush: activityResume thread started
   D/~!uf: New instance of ETSqliteOpenHelper.
   D/~!Registration: Platform: "Android", platformVersion: "5.1.1"
   D/~!Registration: hwid: LGE LGLS675
   D/~!Registration: Registration() initialization complete
   D/~!ETPush: ETPush singleton getInstance initialization completed.
   I/~!ud: SDK is ReadOnly: false
   D/~!ETPush: Google Play Services Version Dependency: 10084000
   I/~!ETPush: Google Play Services Runtime Available: SUCCESS
   D/~!ETPush: Looking for android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED Intent Filter
   I/~!ETPush: Receivers Info Size: 31, Receiver Class Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, Package Name: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   D/~!ETPush: Receiver com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver Found
   D/~!ETPush: Looking for net.onetechnologies.scoresense.MESSAGE_OPENED Intent Filter
   I/~!ETPush: Receivers Info Size: 1, Receiver Class Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, Package Name: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   D/~!ETPush: Receiver com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver Found
   D/~!ETPush: Looking for android.intent.action.AIRPLANE_MODE Intent Filter
   I/~!ETPush: Receivers Info Size: 4, Receiver Class Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, Package Name: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.cmas.transaction.CmasAirplaneModeReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.cmas
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.sprintextension.SprintExtensionBroadcastReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.sprintextension
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.locationlabs.v3client.AirPlaneReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.locationlabs.sparkle.yellow.pre
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   D/~!ETPush: Receiver com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver Found
   D/~!ETPush: Looking for android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN Intent Filter
   I/~!ETPush: Receivers Info Size: 7, Receiver Class Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, Package Name: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.android.settings.powersave.PowerSaveReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.android.settings
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.clock.alarmclock.ALReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.clock
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.clock.timer.TimerReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.clock
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.camera.systeminput.MediaMountStateReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.camera
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.contacts.sim.SimPhonebookStateReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.android.contacts
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.lge.lgdmsclient.receiver.DmReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: com.lge.lgdmsclient
   I/~!ETPush: ActivityInfo Name: com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver, ActivityInfo Package: net.onetechnologies.scoresense
   D/~!ETPush: Receiver com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPushReceiver Found
   D/~!ETPush: checking classes for onEvent.
   D/~!ETPush: confirmed classes for onEvent.
   D/~!ETPush: checking classes for setDatabaseIds.
   D/~!ETPush: confirmed classes for setDatabaseIds.
   D/~!ETPush: checking classes for setId.
   D/~!ETPush: confirmed classes for setId.
   D/~!ETPush: configureSdk() initialization completed
   D/~!ETPush: 1035331432 resuming started...
   D/~!ETPush: Cancelling activityPausedPendingIntent
   D/~!EventBus: Registering com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush with ET EventBus
   D/~!ETPush: Current time: 1499357046650 Pause time: -1
   D/~!ETPush: 1035331432 will notify that app came into foreground...
   D/~!EventBus: postSticky(BackgroundEvent event)
   D/~!EventBus: Registering complete com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush with ET EventBus
   D/~!EventBus: post(BackgroundEvent event) with ET EventBus
   V/~!uh: Verifying Google Play Services ...
   D/~!EventBus: Invoking com.exacttarget.etpushsdk.ETPush.onEvent() with BackgroundEvent
   D/~!ETPush: The application is coming into the foreground.
   D/~!ETPush: Checking for pending registration data.
   D/~!dh: Counting pending registrations.
   D/~!dh: There are 1 pending registrations.
   D/~!ETPush: We have pending registration data to send.
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: Resetting REGISTRATION Alarm Interval to 1.00 minute(s).
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: Resetting REGISTRATION Alarm Active Flag to FALSE
   V/~!uh: Google Play Services is available and meets or exceeds the minimum required version.
   D/~!ETPush: sendRegistration()
   D/~!ETPush: Create Registration if we have a SystemToken.
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: HARD RESET for REGISTRATION Alarm.
   W/~!Registration: An empty or NULL Subscriber Key will not be transmitted to the Marketing Cloud and was NOT updated with the provided value.
   D/~!ETPush: Creating Registration ...
   I/debug: attribute added
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: Resetting REGISTRATION Alarm Interval to 1.00 minute(s).
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: Resetting REGISTRATION Alarm Active Flag to FALSE
   D/~!dh: Counting pending registrations.
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: HARD RESET for REGISTRATION Alarm.
   D/~!uk: createHash(final String string) // string = '{"deviceID":"29257f7b578690c931e501eca9efad9","device_Token":"very long device token","sdk_version":"4.8.4","app_version":"2.3.8 : 209","gcmSenderId":"{gcm_sender_id}","dST":true,"location_enabled":false,"platform_Version":"5.1.1","push_enabled":true,"timeZone":-21600,"platform":"Android","hwid":"LGE LGLS675","etAppId":"{et_app_id}","badge":0,"locale":"en_US","tags":["ALL","Android","Debug"],"attributes":[{"key":"MemberID","value":"appMemberId"}]}'
   D/~!uk: return f62721d758364c5cd4b01dc3f11167b8
   D/~!dh: There are 1 pending registrations.
   D/~!ETPush: There are saved Registrations.  Delete all rows.
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: shouldCreateAlarm() for REGISTRATION Alarm was FALSE.  Aborting alarm creation.
   D/~!EventBus: post(BackgroundEvent event) complete with ET EventBus
   D/~!ETPush: 1035331432 resuming done...
   D/~!ETPush: sendInternalRegistration()
   D/~!ETPush: Create Registration if we have a SystemToken.
   D/~!ETPush: Creating Registration ...
   D/~!dh: Counting pending registrations.
   D/~!dh: There are 1 pending registrations.
   D/~!ETPush: There are saved Registrations.  Delete all rows.
   W/~!Registration: An empty or NULL Subscriber Key will not be transmitted to the Marketing Cloud and was NOT updated with the provided value.
   D/~!uk: createHash(final String string) // string = '{"deviceID":"29257f7b578690c931e501eca9efad9","device_Token":"very long device token","sdk_version":"4.8.4","app_version":"2.3.8 : 209","gcmSenderId":"{gcm_sender_id}","dST":true,"location_enabled":false,"platform_Version":"5.1.1","push_enabled":true,"timeZone":-21600,"platform":"Android","hwid":"LGE LGLS675","etAppId":"{et_app_id}","badge":0,"locale":"en_US","tags":["ALL","Android","Debug"],"attributes":[{"key":"MemberID","value":"appMemberId"}]}'
   D/~!uk: return f62721d758364c5cd4b01dc3f11167b8
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: shouldCreateAlarm() for REGISTRATION Alarm was FALSE.  Aborting alarm creation.
   D/~!dh: Counting pending registrations.
   D/~!dh: There are 1 pending registrations.
   D/~!ETPush: There are saved Registrations.  Create Alarm (if needed) to send them.
   W/~!Registration: An empty or NULL Subscriber Key will not be transmitted to the Marketing Cloud and was NOT updated with the provided value.
   D/~!uk: createHash(final String string) // string = '{"deviceID":"29257f7b578690c931e501eca9efad9","device_Token":"very long device token","sdk_version":"4.8.4","app_version":"2.3.8 : 209","gcmSenderId":"{gcm_sender_id}","dST":true,"location_enabled":false,"platform_Version":"5.1.1","push_enabled":true,"timeZone":-21600,"platform":"Android","hwid":"LGE LGLS675","etAppId":"{et_app_id}","badge":0,"locale":"en_US","tags":["ALL","Android","Debug"],"attributes":[{"key":"MemberID","value":"appMemberId"}]}'
   D/~!uk: return f62721d758364c5cd4b01dc3f11167b8
   D/~!ETAlarmManager: shouldCreateAlarm() for REGISTRATION Alarm was FALSE.  Aborting alarm creation.
   D/~!ETPush: Pausing as a result of callback? 'true'
   D/~!ETPush: activityResumedThread is not running.  So continue with pausing activity.
   D/~!ETPush: 1035331432 resuming started...
   D/~!ETPush: Set Alarm for 15 seconds from now to handle background work.
   D/~!ETPush: Save time for onResume() to determine if in foreground.
   D/~!ETPush: 1035331432 pausing done...
   D/~!ETPush: Resuming as a result of callback? 'true'
   D/~!ETPush: activityPausedThread is not running.  So continue with resuming activity.
   D/~!ETPush: activityResume thread started
   D/~!ETPush: 59699254 resuming started...
   D/~!ETPush: Cancelling activityPausedPendingIntent
   D/~!ETPush: Current time: 1499357048335 Pause time: 1499357048197
   D/~!ETPush: pause_time_key removed
   D/~!ETPush: 59699254 resuming done...
```

Comment: Which of the two log messages are you seeing?  If the attribute is failing to be added by the SDK then a reason will be output to the logs.  If you're seeing "attribute added" from your application then please provide the Registration payload from the logs.  Be sure to sanitize it as you have your screenshot.

Comment: If you could please provide a Registration payload to your question that would be immensely helpful.

Comment: I'll need a Registration payload to troubleshoot further.  Also, if this is a new implementation I would HIGHLY encourage you to use the 5.x release of the SDK.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, needed to format the logs. See the updated response. @BillMote

Comment: I can see that your Registration payload has been successfully sent to the MarketingCloud Servers.  I'm discussing your issue with the services team.

Comment: The services team asked that you open a support ticket through your account manager as they'll need your MID in order to investigate this issue any further.  It would be worth double-checking that you have everything squared away with regards to the Application, custom Attribute, etc. within your application's account settings first.  Also, note, your attributes must be setup on the server side first and they are case/white-space sensitive.

Also, if you're early enough in your development cycle, please use SDK version 5.x for Android.

Comment: Reference or provide all the data in your posted question to expedite the process for the services engineers.  The important piece will be the log line beginning with `createHash` as it contains the `MemberID` attribute, your Device ID, etc.